# pass value by reference in constructor, save it, then modify it later, how to?

Tags: c#, parameters, reference, int

How do I implement this functionality?  I think its not working because I save it in the constructor?
Do I need to do some Box/Unbox jiberish?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int currentInt = 1;

        //Should be 1
        Console.WriteLine(currentInt);
        //is 1

        TestClass tc = new TestClass(ref currentInt);

        //should be 1
        Console.WriteLine(currentInt);
        //is 1

        tc.modInt();

        //should be 2
        Console.WriteLine(currentInt);
        //is 1  :(
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int testInt;

        public TestClass(ref int testInt)
        {
            this.testInt = testInt;
        }

        public void modInt()
        {
            testInt = 2;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't, basically. Not directly. The "pass by reference" aliasing is only valid within the method itself.

The closest you could come is have a mutable wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Wrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Wrapper<int> wrapper = new Wrapper<int>(1);
...
TestClass tc = new TestClass(wrapper);

Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Value); // 1
tc.ModifyWrapper();
Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Value); // 2

...

class TestClass
{
    private readonly Wrapper<int> wrapper;

    public TestClass(Wrapper<int> wrapper)
    {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void ModifyWrapper()
    {
        wrapper.Value = 2;
    }
}
```

You may find Eric Lippert's recent blog post on ["ref returns and ref locals"](https://ericlippert.com/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals/) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can come close, but it is really just Jon's answer in disguise:

```vb
 Sub Main()

     Dim currentInt = 1

     'Should be 1
     Console.WriteLine(currentInt)
     'is 1

     Dim tc = New Action(Sub()currentInt+=1)

     'should be 1
     Console.WriteLine(currentInt)
     'is 1

     tc.Invoke()

     'should be 2
     Console.WriteLine(currentInt)
     'is 2  :)
 End Sub
```